# XSLT additional templates for reading XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I have some XSL which is used as part of our software product, which works fine and outputs text into a PDF:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.1" 
            xmlns:smf="http://www.thisisnumero.com/xml/smartagent/4.0/smf"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
            xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" 
            xmlns:smfx="xalan://com.thisisnumero.smartagent.gwutil.SMFTools"
            xmlns:datetime="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"
            xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan"
            exclude-result-prefixes="fo"
            xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
            extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/smf:workItem">

    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">

        <fo:layout-master-set>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first-page" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="0.5cm"  margin-bottom="1cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-top="15mm" margin-left="16mm" margin-right="26mm" margin-bottom="45mm"/>
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-first" extent="0mm" margin-left="1mm" margin-right="0mm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer-normal" extent="42mm" />
                <fo:region-end border-top-width="5pt" region-name="right-sidebar" writing-mode="tb-rl" extent="10mm" />                 
            </fo:simple-page-master>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="all-pages" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="0.5cm"  margin-bottom="1cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-left="16mm" margin-right="26mm" margin-top="1.27cm" margin-bottom="1mm" /> 
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-normal" extent="0mm" />
                <fo:region-after region-name="footer-normal" extent="0mm" />            
            </fo:simple-page-master>

            <fo:simple-page-master master-name="AdditionalInfoPage" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm" margin-top="0.5cm"  margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm">
                <fo:region-body margin-right="1.75cm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1mm" /> 
                <fo:region-before region-name="header-normal" extent="0mm" />                   
            </fo:simple-page-master>        

            <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="document" font-family="Helvetica">
                <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="first" master-reference="first-page"/>
                    <fo:conditional-page-master-reference page-position="any" master-reference="all-pages" />
                </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            </fo:page-sequence-master>

        </fo:layout-master-set>     

        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document">                                                                  
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">   
                <fo:block font-size="10pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" wrap-option="wrap">                                            
                    <xsl:value-of select="smf:body"/>                                   
                </fo:block>                                                                                                             
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>                     
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

Retaining what is already there, I need to make amendments to the above to reference a separate XML document/file so I can output some data. This is an example of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<class>
   <student rollno="393">
      <firstname>Dinkar</firstname>
      <lastname>Kad</lastname>
      <nickname>Dinkar</nickname>
      <marks>85</marks>
   </student>
   <student rollno="493">
      <firstname>Vaneet</firstname>
      <lastname>Gupta</lastname>
      <nickname>Vinni</nickname>
      <marks>95</marks>
   </student>
</class>
```

As per one of the answers, I tried adding this to my XSL:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('afford_xml.xml')"/>
```

I then just tried referencing the XML an a separate block below everything else:

```
    <xsl:template match="class/student">                                        
    <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">                  
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document">                                                              
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <fo:block font-size="10pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" wrap-option="wrap">    
                    Do for-each....
                </fo:block>
                <fo:block font-size="10pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" wrap-option="wrap">    
                    <xsl:for-each select="class/student">
                        Roll:<xsl:value-of select="@rollno"/>
                        First Name: <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
                        Last Name: <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
                        Marks: <xsl:value-of select="marks"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </fo:block>                                                                             
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>                     
    </fo:root>
</xsl:template>
```

This however does not work. I am not sure if it is in the right place or if there is something else I need to do to get it to work. I am assuming you can reference more than one template in an XSL document? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too vague. In general, you need to use the `document()` function to refer to an external XML file.

Comment: I have amended the question which should hopefully make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document">                                                                  
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">   
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" wrap-option="wrap">                                            
                <xsl:value-of select="smf:body"/>                                   
            </fo:block>                                                                                                             
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
```

you need to make sure the other document or some of its nodes are processed, for instance by changing that code to

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="document">                                                                  
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">   
            <fo:block font-size="10pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" wrap-option="wrap">                                            
                <xsl:value-of select="smf:body"/>                                   
            </fo:block> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document('afford_xml.xml')/class/student"/>                                                                                                            
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
```

and then writing a template for those `student` elements in the other document e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="class/student">
           <fo:block font-size="10pt" linefeed-treatment="preserve" white-space-collapse="false" white-space-treatment="ignore-if-surrounding-linefeed" wrap-option="wrap">    

                    Roll:<xsl:value-of select="@rollno"/>
                    First Name: <xsl:value-of select="firstname"/>
                    Last Name: <xsl:value-of select="lastname"/>
                    Marks: <xsl:value-of select="marks"/>

            </fo:block>            
</xsl:template>
```

So your approach of writing template(s) for the element(s) in the other document is fine, only you need to make sure they are processed as indicated. If you need more help then you need to explain which FO elements you want to create for a `student` element in the input.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have added further information to my question  hopefully to make it a bit clearer. I have tried to adapt some of your comments though but just not quite there.

Comment: Well you need to decide whether you want to process the `student` elements with `for-each` or with `apply-templates`, mixing both does not make sense. And the FO document structure is also already defined, so setting it up a second time does not make sense. I have edited the answer and made changes to process the input sample you have shown, obviously the output of each student can be refined, but that is more a FO problem than an XSLT problem.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I have got it working. Your comments make sense now and thinking about it I can just use `param` instead of `apply-templates` to reference my XML file `<xsl:param name="file1" select="document($xmlfileName)"/> `. I have also stripped out the duplication of the FO structure. Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinWing, if your problem is solved, you can accept the answer. As for using a parameter, I don't see how that solves the problem of having the second document processed. You would still need to do `<xsl:apply-templates select="$file1//student"/>` or `<xsl:for-each select="$file1//student">...</xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: Apologies, I have opted to use the `<xsl:for-each select="$file1//student">...</xsl:for-each>` option.

Comment: When using `for-each`, do you know how we can specify a particular node? So I am using `<xsl:for-each select="$file1//student">...</xsl:for-each>` but if I only wanted display values for a certain student (rollno="393"), what would I need to add into the `for-each` statement?

Comment: Start with an XPath tutorial and learn how to use a predicate in an expression `<xsl:for-each select="$file1//student[@rollno = 393]">...</xsl:for-each>`.